# How to find unknown repeated patterns in the set of strings?

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-recognition, bigdata

Here is description of a problem. Suppose you have a set of strings (up to 10 billion of strings, each string length up to 10k characters, there are 1000 unique symbols string could be constructed from). How can I find patterns with length from 2 up to length N (lets say 10 for simplicity). Also I'd like to see only those patterns which occurs at least in 1% of all string (some threshold).

I'd like to find an algorithm which can help me solve this problem. The numbers are not exact but are the same order of magnitude as we have in project.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Index all your strings in a suffix tree ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)). This can be O(number of characters) and you only need to do it once before you start.

A suffix tree allows you to quickly(O(pattern length)) tell if a pattern appears in any of the strings you've indexed, and how many times.

You can do another pass through the structure and count the number of leafs in each subtree (O(N) again) and that tells you how often you can find the substring from the root to that node, so you can drop them or do whatever you want based on how common they are.

Now, 10 billion strings of length 10k, with 2 byte characters (to fit the 1000 unique symbols) is quite large (18TB if my math is right) which doesn't fit in ram. So you'll either need to wait for a while or get more computers and setup a distributted solution. You can apply the solution above to batches of strings so that they fit into your available memory, but the lookup in the structure needs to be multiplied by the number of batches you are doing.

If everything is in batches then the most efficient way would be to make batches as big as you can, then when you've build the suffix tree for a batch run all your queries through it, save the results and drop the tree to free memory for the next batch of input strings.

Comment: If you just count the number of leaves below a node, you will be counting the total number of appearances of the pattern (*including* multiple appearances within the same string), rather than what the OP asked for (namely, the total number of strings within which the pattern appears).  But your way is fast, and TTBOMK counting the latter requires storing at each node the *set* of strings that have leaves below it, and computing unions during the DFS, which multiplies up the time and space complexity, so maybe this is good enough.

Comment: I think I didn't get an idea of batching. Suppose I've splitted my input into reasonable size batches my computer/cluster can process at once - shouldn't I merge all those batches at the end to get right answer? Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right, you need to merge the results at the end to get the right answer. I assumed that part is obvious.